# Angular checking if two input fields are the same without hitting submit

Tags: angular, angular5

In my angular app, I have a form that has two input fields :

email and confirm email.

```html
<label for="exampleInputEmail1">New Email</label>
<input type="email" class="form-control">
<label for="exampleInputEmail1">Confirm </label>
<input type="email" class="form-control">
```

Is it possible, that when the user is typing on the second field, once he has left the field without clicking a submit button to check if these two fields are the same and then apply custom class with style to it?

Is it done on ngModel changed ? how is it usually checked ?

I am new to angular so any help is appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check while the user is typing you can use something like this:

```html
<input class="form-control" [ngModel]="confirmEmail" (ngModelChange)="checkEmail($event)"/>
```

And check if the two fields match in a method, where `$event` will be the value of the input field.

You can also do it on blur:

```html
<input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="confirmEmail" (blur)="checkEmail(confirmEmail)"/>
```

Here, you take the value of the field with `[(ngModel)]="confirmEmail"` and can see if it matches the previous field in a method.

Answer (score 0):

```js
checkSame(secEmail: string) {
  this.secondEmail = secEmail;
  if (this.secondEmail === this.firstEmail) {
    // stuff for form control
  } else {
    // form control with errors
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="exampleInputEmail1">New Email</label>
<input type="email" name="firstEmail" [(ngModel)]="firstEmail" class="form-control">
<label for="exampleInputEmail1">Confirm </label>
<input type="email" name="secondEmail" [ngModel]="secondEmail" class="form-control" (ngModelChange)="checkSame($event)">
```

This will validate the email match only when the second email changes. If you want to check also when the frist one changes, use the same `ngModelChange` as on the second input field.